# Why does my list productsCombined[] change after running my for loop? How can I change this code so it doesn't? You will see the prints diverge at TAC

Tags: python, list, for-loop

I was expecting the lists to all print the same values before and after the for loop is run. I don't think what the code does is as relevant but it is supposed to create 4 strings that when placed next to each other keep the corresponding text values in row / spaced properly.
Ex:

Example of what the code does to the lists

[image: 1]

For some reason, the for loop is changing the values of my list and when I expect "TAC" to be the next product in the string it is somehow "Silestone" and many of the following products in the string come out as silestone as opposed to their corresponding list value.

```
import math


productsCombined = ['Silestone', '4in. Backsplash', 'Half-Bullnose Edge ', 'BulletProof®', 'Custom Radius Corner', 'Waterfall', 'Marble (Level 7) (3cm)', 'Custom Height Backsplash', '1/4 Round Edge', 'Regular', 'TAC', '4in. Backsplash', 'Half-Bullnose Edge ', 'Regular', 'Cutouts and Holes', 'K1830402-J', '134BLNO440177', 'W3182716-1', 'US-1512-biscuit', 'P0145402', 'DSA-WD5000', 'Dishwasher Bracket', 'Other', 'Other', 'Template', 'Tear-out and Disposal', 'High Bar Cutdown', 'Standard Install', 'Rush Install', 'Plumbing', 'Layout Approval', 'Payment Method']
descriptionsCombined = ['Name: 1 super mega slab of igneous blue 3cm Counter SQFT: 20.0 Backsplash SQFT: 4.0', 'Using Material 1', 'Material 1. Laminated.', 'Material 1.', 'Material 1. " Corner Radius', 'Material 1.', 'Material 2 - From a Remnant Location: NFM', 'Using Material 2 Height: 24.0"', 'Material 2.', 'Material 2.', 'Material 3. Name: 1 jumbo slab calactatta gold 2cm Counter SQFT: 55.0 Backsplash SQFT: 8.0', 'Using Material 3', 'Material 3. Laminated.', 'Material 3.', '1.0 Undermount Double Sink Cutout(s) 1.0 Undermount Single Sink Cutout(s) 1.0 Overmount Double Sink Cutout(s) 1.0 Overmount Single Sink Cutout(s) 1.0 Appliance Cutout(s) 1.0 Outlet Cutout(s) 1.0 Faucet Hole(s) ', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', 'Cobra', 'Leoploredon', 'Ready for Template: No - Waiting on cabinets', '', '', "NOT a 'Rush Job'", 'Install on or Before: 03-22-2023', 'Sinks Requiring Plumbing: 2.0 Bath Sinks 1.0 Kitchen Sinks - Other Plumbing Items: Installation of Garbage Disposal Installation of Water Filter ', '', 'Credit Card (3% Charge)']
quantitiesCombined = ['1.0', '4.0', '5.0', '20.0', '3.0', '2.0', '32.0', '5.0', '5.0', '32.0', '1.0', '8.0', '22.0', '55.0', '1', '1.0', '1.0', '1.0', '1.0', '1.0', '1.0', '1.0', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1']
pricesCombined = ['2560.0', '128.0', '42.0', '10.0', '125.0', '375.0', '62.0', '62.0', '0.0', '2.0', '5280.0', '96.0', '42.0', '2.0', '770.0', '485.0', '850.0', '420.0', '90.0', '100.0', '350.0', '75.0', '120.0', '560.0', '0', '1070.0', '750.0', '0', '1854.2', '1150.0', '0', '598.521']

# Outputs
productsString = ""
descriptionsString = ""
quantitiesString = ""
pricesString = ""

for i in range(0,len(productsCombined)):
    print(productsCombined[i])
    linesProducts = math.ceil(len(str(productsCombined[i])) / 47)
    linesDescriptions = math.ceil(len(str(descriptionsCombined[i])) / 47)
    linesQuantities = 1
    linesPrices = 1
    maxLines = max(linesProducts, linesDescriptions)
    if linesProducts >= maxLines:
        productsString += "\n" + "\n" + str(productsCombined[i]) + "\n_____________________________________"
    else:
        additionalLines = "\n"
        linesToAdd = maxLines - linesProducts
        for i in range(0, linesToAdd):
            additionalLines += "\n"
        productsString += "\n" + "\n" + str(productsCombined[i]) + additionalLines + "_____________________________________"
    if linesDescriptions >= maxLines:
        descriptionsString += "\n" + "\n" + str(descriptionsCombined[i]) + "\n_____________________________________"
    else:
        additionalLines = "\n"
        linesToAdd = maxLines - linesDescriptions
        for i in range(0, linesToAdd):
            additionalLines += "\n"
        descriptionsString += "\n" + "\n" + str(descriptionsCombined[i]) + additionalLines + "_____________________________________"
    if linesQuantities >= maxLines:
        quantitiesString += "\n" + "\n" + str(quantitiesCombined[i]) + "\n_____________________________________"
    else:
        additionalLines = "\n"
        linesToAdd = maxLines - linesQuantities
        for i in range(0, linesToAdd):
            additionalLines += "\n"
        quantitiesString += "\n" + "\n" + str(quantitiesCombined[i]) + additionalLines + "_____________________________________"
    if linesPrices >= maxLines:
        pricesString += "\n" + "\n" + str(pricesCombined[i]) + "\n_____________________________________"
    else:
        additionalLines = "\n"
        linesToAdd = maxLines - linesPrices
        for i in range(0, linesToAdd):
            additionalLines += "\n"
        pricesString += "\n" + "\n" + str(pricesCombined[i]) + additionalLines + "_____________________________________"
    print(productsCombined[i])
    print("\n")
```

Comment: You're reusing the variable `i` in the loop `for i in range(0, linesToAdd)`. After that, all the `xxxCombined[i]` use that new `i` instead of the one from `for i in range(0, len(productsCombined)):`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Get out of the habit of using `for index in range(len(list)):`. Use `for item in list:` or `for index, item in enumerate(list):`

Comment: @barmar the variable i was the simplest solution I simply swapped my nested for loops with j and this fixed it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the idea is to get a printout like in your image, then you can get away with simply:

```
import textwrap
from itertools import zip_longest

# ... the data lists here ...

value_widths = [35, 35, 10, 10]  # specify a width for each column

for values in zip(productsCombined, descriptionsCombined, quantitiesCombined, pricesCombined):
    # Use `textwrap.wrap` to line-wrap the values onto 1 or more lines of `width` characters
    # (could be longer if there's a very long word); use `zip` 
    # to iterate over the column widths in parallel
    wrapped_values = [textwrap.wrap(value, width) for value, width in zip(values, value_widths)]
    # Iterate over the wrapped lines, using `zip_longest` so "cells"
    # with less lines than others work correctly (as opposed to `zip`
    # that would use the shortest iterable)
    for line in zip_longest(*wrapped_values, fillvalue=""):
        # Justify each cell to exactly width characters
        # (this will ruthlessly clip very long words!)
        justified_line = [value.ljust(width)[:width] for value, width in zip(line, value_widths)]
        # Print out the cell lines, with a space in between
        print(" ".join(justified_line))
    # Print out the row divider lines
    print(" ".join("_" * width for width in value_widths))
```

This prints out

```
Silestone                           Name: 1 super mega slab of igneous  1.0        2560.0    
                                    blue 3cm Counter SQFT: 20.0                              
                                    Backsplash SQFT: 4.0                                     
___________________________________ ___________________________________ __________ __________
4in. Backsplash                     Using Material 1                    4.0        128.0     
___________________________________ ___________________________________ __________ __________
Half-Bullnose Edge                  Material 1. Laminated.              5.0        42.0      
___________________________________ ___________________________________ __________ __________
[... snip ...]
```

You could further adjust this to use `.rjust` for the numeric columns for a better layout.

If you really do need each column as a separate list, that's easy too:

```
output_lines = []
for values in ...:
    # ... instead of printing the justified line, append the list
    output_lines.append([value.ljust(width)[:width] for value, width in zip(line, value_widths)])
    # ... and instead of printing the divider, append the list
    output_lines.append(["_" * width for width in value_widths])
# ... finally, use the `zip(*...)` pattern to transpose the N-length list of 4 columns to a 4-tuple of N-length tuples:

a, b, c, d = zip(*output_lines)
```

`b` will then start with

```
('Name: 1 super mega slab of igneous ', 'blue 3cm Counter SQFT: 20.0        ', 'Backsplash SQFT: 4.0               ', '___________________________________',
```

etc.

Comment: Thank you so much this is extremally helpful and eye opening to how much I have still to learn. This was my first post here and I am excited to be more involved in this community.